# Incluir Tabela dinâmica no ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu incluo os dados de uma table dinamicamente em AJAX, e funciona perfeitamente para incluir na tabela, o que acontece, é que agora preciso dos dados da tabela no controller, e por utilizar .NET CORE, não estou conseguindo pegar os dados via JSON.
Como posso colocar o ViewBag para receber os dados da minha tabela, e utilizá-los no controle ? Aqui é a forma que incluo na tabela:

```
  if (data.resultado) {
                $("#tablepesquisaprodutos").append("<tr class='item'>"
                    + "<td>" + CodigoProduto + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + DescricaoProduto + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + Qtd + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + PrecoCusto + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + DescontoP + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + DescontoV + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + Total.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + ICMS + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + AliquotaICMS.replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + vICMS.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + ISS.replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + vISS.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + IPI.replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + vIPI.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + "</td>"
                    + "<td align='right'>" +
                    "<a class='link-excluir' data-id=" + CodigoProduto + " href='#' title='Excluir'><i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg'></i></a>"
                    + "</td>"
                    + "<td><div style='visibility: hidden;'>" + QtdFalta + "</div></td>"
                    + "<td><div style='visibility: hidden;'>" + ProdutoID + "</div></td>"
                    + "</tr>")
                getTotal();
                $("#produtoid").val("");
                $("#idproduto").val("");
                $("#qtd").val("");
                $("#precocusto").val("");
                $("#descontov").val("");
                $("#descontop").val("");
                $("#icms").val("");
                $("#aliquotaicms").html("");
                $("#ipi").val("");
                $("#iss").val("");
                $("#dataentrega").val("");
                $("#descricaoproduto").html("");
            }
```

Comment: Oi Mariana, ainda não tive a oportunidade de trabalhar com .net core, mas acredito que talvez esse link possa te ajudar a fazer o acionamento da sua controller através do ajax para transmitir esses dados. Segue o link: https://liftcodeplay.com/2017/02/14/using-asp-net-core-and-jquery-to-call-methods-via-ajax/

Comment: @SérgioLopes infelizmente não ajudou, mesmo assim obrigado.